# Search edit text using rxJava. How to convert snippet of code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I just copied snippet of code in java and automatically convert to kotlin using ide,
but here is it my error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqwi8.jpg

```
disposable.add(
                publishSubject
                        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .distinctUntilChanged()
                        .switchMapSingle(new Function<String, Single<List<Contact>>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Single<List<Contact>> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                                return apiService.getContacts(null, s)
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
                            }
                        })
                        .subscribeWith(observer));
```

Could you help me to convert it to kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go like this:

```
        disposable.add(
                publishSubject
                        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .distinctUntilChanged()
                        .switchMapSingle { s ->
                            apiService.getContacts(null, s)
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        }
                        .subscribeWith(observer))
```

Your `Function` must be coming from `import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function`